# Jquery JScrollPane under FF 10 miscomputing content height during initialise()

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane, firefox-10

When jscrollpane initialise() is adding it's wrapping divs, I can see from firebug stepping that my contents are not laying out the same as they do before the wrapping-div's are added.

In particular, my content is two float left divs that fit side by side before the wrapping-divs but one below the other afterword, thus a vertical scroll is added even though none is needed.

And after the vertical scroll is in there, my two divs return to their side by side positions.

When the code:

```
// Make the pane thinner to allow for the vertical scrollbar
pane.width(paneWidth - scrollbarWidth - originalPaddingTotalWidth);
```

finally executes, the divs jump back to where they should have been.

Any suggestions? or more info needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`display:inline-block`](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/) instead of `float:left` to avoid the inadvertent [float/drop](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/basic-float-drop.html). Look out for [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) issues when encountering this type of behaviour for future reference.